# What is the term for number of descendants, weighted by genetic relatedness?

Tags: dna

There are terms for 1) number of children 2) number of grandchildren - but for longer timescales, where you would like to talk about the total genetic contribution still surviving, what terms are there?

For example, Genghis Khan is often described as having millions of descendants. But does that really mean anything?  What is the term for that number, weighted by the likely distribution of their actual genetic relatedness?

So the question is for the population genetics term for actual surviving contribution of a specific genetic ancestor.

Comment: A bigger question, perhaps, would be whether the specific genetic inheritance from that particular ancestor could even be determined, if decendancy from someone that far back could be proven for a large number of those decendants.  I've been able to confirm shared DNA between 5 and 6 cM at the 9th cousin level twice, but even then that's going only to the 1600s, and is a quite rare case.  Generally, anything under 7 cM isn't going to be able to be confirmed, and essentially noone will have a verifiable tree reaching to the 1200s.

Comment: I think the closest _phrasing_ for what you want, would be to specify the number of generations applicable, such as x descendants in 10 generations (sum of all descendants) or x descendants in the 10th generation (count of a particular level of relatedness). Not as precise as exact numbers of children, grandchildren, etc, but more succinct.

Comment: Yes basically I want the population genetics term for total expected current surviving genetic contribution to the population.